# How to integrate React with Footable

Tags: reactjs, footable

i am new to react. Suppose i am using footable for my purpose. I saw some example from below link

https://www.npmjs.com/package/footable

But when i did that its having an error with footable is not a fuction.

I think the error occured in below code in which footable is not recognizing by react

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.table').footable();
});
```

Does i want to import any thing? any suggestion will be much appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that you're missing a library.

On the page that you linked, it is written to include:

```
<script src="path_to_your_js/footable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Obviously the "path_to_your_js/footable.js" has to change to be your own path.  Also  you should know that this is a *jQuery* plugin and has no connection with react js library.